# Не получается посчитать сумму цифр в числе через деление с остатком

Tags: java, алгоритм

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 10;
        Integer[] arr = {102, 140, 172,
                140, 293, 69,
                36, 144, 82,
                44, 205, 41,
                30, 10 ,193,
                348, 79, 176,
                396, 145, 43,
                193, 132, 2,
                226, 170, 43,
                127, 136, 165};
        int s = 0;
        int ost;

        for (int i = 0; i<n; i++){
            int ch = arr[i*3]*arr[i*3+1]+arr[i*3+2]; // число, сумму цифр которого надо посчитать.
            for (int a = 0; a<Integer.toString(ch).length(); a++){
                ost = ch%10;
                ch /= 10;
                s += ost;
            }
            System.out.print(s+" ");
            s = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Задача состоит в нахождении суммы цифр числа, путем деления с остатком. Вроде детская ошибка, но не могу найти.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас в цикле условие

```
Integer.toString(ch)
```

Но затем внутри цикла вы меняете значение переменной ch, т.е. правая граница меняется вместе с ней. Можно сделать что-то такое:

```
int len = Integer.toString(ch).length();
for (int a = 0; a< len; a++){
            ost = ch%10;
            ch /= 10;
            s += ost;
        }
```

Также скажу, что длину числа вычислять вовсе не обязательно, можно просто написать

```
while(ch>0) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

Возьмите карандаш и листок бумаги. Выполните Ваш код шаг за шагом, записывая промежуточные значения переменных (особенно, длину `toString(ch)`). Всё увидите.

P.S.

Учтите, что в условии остановки цикла операнды вычисляются на каждой итерации.

Answer (score 2):

Сергей, если я правильно понял задачу Вам надо посчитать сумму цифр в числе. То есть если число `102`, то результат должен быть `1+0+2=3`.

Я не совсем понял вашу конструкцию с тремя последовательными числами, но для подсчета суммы цифр у меня получилось вот так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int numberOfDigits = (int) (Math.log10(arr[i]) + 1);
    int divider = Double.valueOf(Math.pow(10, numberOfDigits)).intValue();
    int sum = 0;
    while (divider != 1) {
        sum += arr[i] % divider / (divider / 10);
        divider /= 10;
    }
    System.out.println("Sum of digits for " + arr[i] + "=" + sum);
}
```

Результат выполнения для Вашего массива:

```
Sum of digits for 102=3
Sum of digits for 140=5
Sum of digits for 172=10
Sum of digits for 140=5
Sum of digits for 293=14
Sum of digits for 69=15
Sum of digits for 36=9
Sum of digits for 144=9
Sum of digits for 82=10
Sum of digits for 44=8
```

Надеюсь это то, что Вы ищите.